# How to video capture a windows mobile phone?

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to make a tutorial and I am wondering if there is a way to do the tutorial as a video. I was thinking of using like the emulator and capturing it from there but is there better ways since I have to connect to a webservice and the emulator usually is so much slower then it being on the real device. I don't want to give people the impression that the application is slow when it really is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at

- [Ilium Software Screen Capture](http://www.iliumsoft.com/site/fp/screen_capture.php) (free)
- [RiverPast Windows Mobile Recorder](http://www.riverpast.com/en/prod/wmrecorder/) (50$)
- [MyMobiler](http://www.mymobiler.com/) (free)

Answer (score 0):

Also you could look at using Pocket Controller from [SOTI](http://www.soti.net/), it allows you to control a device from your pc and then I guess you could record on the pc. Sorta like the emulator, but does allow you to use skins for most of the devices out there